# Gnuplot not plotting negative values of x**(1/3)

Tags: gnuplot

This is the correct graph of x^(1/3):

[image: Normal graph of x^(1/3)]

However, when trying to plot `x**(1./3)` on gnuplot, this is what I get:

[image: Graph of x^(1/3) using gnuplot]

How can I fix this?

Additionally, it is not the first time that gnuplot doesn't plot values around zero in other functions (when it is supposed to, of course: I'm not talking about asymptotes etc.). What can I do?

Comment: Can you provide your code? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: @ChristianYami    Sure, this is the command I used:


`plot x**(1./3)`

As you can see, I included a dot after 1. If I don't do that, gnuplot won't perform the division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `Gnuplot` doesn't plot or calculate `x**(1/3.)` for negative numbers (in real numbers world) is because it treats power function as logarithm functions: `x^n = exp(ln(x^n)) = exp(nln(x))`, where `ln(x)` is the natural logarithm. Notice that `x^n = exp(n ln(x))` has its domain in `x > 0`.

Of course, we can compute `ln(x)` for `x<0` using complex numbers (as we can see when compute `(-8)^(1/3.)`)

Answer (score 6):

The reason why your graph is not drawn closer to zero is because there is a default sampling of 100,
i.e. your function will be plotted with 100 points within your xrange.
If you increase this number, this will get you closer to zero. Check `help samples`.

About the missing negative values, this seems to be a bit special in gnuplot.
I guess `x**b` where `b` is a floating point number is special.
You can test the examples:

```
print sqrt(4)
print 4**0.5
print sqrt(-4)
print (-4)**0.5
print 8**(1./3)
print (-8)**(1./3)
```

which will give:

```
2.0
2.0
{0.0, 2.0}
{1.22460635382238e-16, 2.0}   # rounding error {0.0, 2.0}
2.0
{1.0, 1.73205080756888}       # 1 out of 3 valid solutions, but not the expected -2
```

Values in `{Re, Im}` are imaginary numbers. First the real part then the imaginary part.
In order to get your plot nevertheless you can try the following:

**Code:**

```
### cube root
reset session

set samples 500
set grid xtics, ytics

cuberoot(x) = sgn(x)*abs(x)**(1./3)

plot cuberoot(x) w l
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

I'll try to explain, but I'm not a mathematician. For the N-th root there are N solutions.
Apparently, gnuplot takes one of them. Apparently, one with a positive real part, and if there are several, the one with the smallest positive imaginary part. I guess it is called "principal root". Check also [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubeRoot.html).

So, this will explain why

```
print (-8)**(1./3)
print (-8)**(1./9)  # 9th root
```

will return

```
{1.0, 1.73205}          # and not -2
{1.18393, 0.4309183}    # and not -1.25992
```

**Code:**

```
### roots
reset session

set size ratio -1
set xlabel "real part"
set xrange [-3:3]
set ylabel "imaginary part"
set yrange [-3:3]
set grid xtics, ytics

set angle degrees
NRootRe(x,N,i) = -sgn(x)*abs(x)**(1./N)*cos(360.*i/N - 180*sgn(x))
NRootIm(x,N,i) = -sgn(x)*abs(x)**(1./N)*sin(360.*i/N - 180*sgn(x))

x = -8
do for [N=3:9:2] {
    do for [i=1:N] {
        print sprintf('x=%g, N=%g, i=%g: {% 9g, % 9g}',x,N,i,NRootRe(x,N,i), NRootIm(x,N,i))
    }
    print ""
}

plot for [N=3:9:2] [i=1:N:1] '+' u (0):(0):(NRootRe(x,N,i)):(NRootIm(x,N,i)) w vec ti sprintf("x=%g, N=%g",x,N)
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
x=-8, N=3, i=1: {        1,  -1.73205}
x=-8, N=3, i=2: {        1,   1.73205}
x=-8, N=3, i=3: {       -2,  7.34764e-16}

x=-8, N=5, i=1: {-0.468382,  -1.44153}
x=-8, N=5, i=2: {  1.22624, -0.890916}
x=-8, N=5, i=3: {  1.22624,  0.890916}
x=-8, N=5, i=4: {-0.468382,   1.44153}
x=-8, N=5, i=5: { -1.51572,  5.56847e-16}

x=-8, N=7, i=1: {-0.839155,  -1.05227}
x=-8, N=7, i=2: { 0.299491,  -1.31216}
x=-8, N=7, i=3: {  1.21261, -0.583964}
x=-8, N=7, i=4: {  1.21261,  0.583964}
x=-8, N=7, i=5: { 0.299491,   1.31216}
x=-8, N=7, i=6: {-0.839155,   1.05227}
x=-8, N=7, i=7: {  -1.3459,  4.94459e-16}

x=-8, N=9, i=1: {-0.965156, -0.809862}
x=-8, N=9, i=2: {-0.218783,  -1.24078}
x=-8, N=9, i=3: { 0.629961,  -1.09112}
x=-8, N=9, i=4: {  1.18394, -0.430918}
x=-8, N=9, i=5: {  1.18394,  0.430918}
x=-8, N=9, i=6: { 0.629961,   1.09112}
x=-8, N=9, i=7: {-0.218783,   1.24078}
x=-8, N=9, i=8: {-0.965156,  0.809862}
x=-8, N=9, i=9: { -1.25992,  4.62872e-16}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why `print (-8)**(1./3)` yields the particular complex value `{1.0, 1.73205080756888}`, but please note that it *is* a valid solution to the equation.  There are an infinite number of solutions forming a set of lines in the complex plane.

Comment: @Ethan, right, it _is_ a valid solution. I modified the answer with an attempt to explain.

Comment: That's not what is going on. This gets complicated. I'll amend my answer with a figure it has taken quite a while for me to figure out how to draw.  In short, complex results from `cpow(x,y)` are chosen so that they form a continuous surface.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I found it very informative and it helped me solve my problem (and also, they made me aware of the fact that I have to expand my knowledge of it-just for the sake of learning it). If you can recommend a book that I can read to learn more, I will highly appreciate it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The cube root of x for x < 0 is a surface of complex values.  Gnuplot cannot easily plot that.  The plot you show is presumably for

```
f(x) = sgn(x) * abs(x)**(1./3)
```

which is the intersection of that complex surface with the plane Imag(z) = 0.
(Edit: see supplementary figures).

An alternative plot that makes intuitive sense is to plot x as the cube of y.

```
plot [t=-2:2] (t**3):(t) with lines
```

[image]

**Supplementary figures**

**Figure 1**) The first figure shows why the 'simple' root that lies along the negative real axis is undesireable because it runs along a discontinuity in the imaginary component of the complex surface.

```
set title "Discontinuous imaginary component along negative real axis"
set yrange [-.1:.1]
set xrange [-10:10]
set xlabel "Real"
set ylabel "Imaginary"
set xyplane 0
set grid x y z vertical

f(x,y) = (x + I*y) ** (1./3)

splot real(f(x,y)), imag(f(x,y)), abs(f(x,y)), \
      [-10:10] '+' using (x):(0):(sgn(x)*abs(x)**(1./3)) with lines lt -1 lw 2 title "cuberoot(x)"
```

[image]

**Figure 2**  This figure shows the complex surface of solutions to the equation `(Z)**(1/3)`.  For each plane of constant Z the solutions lie on three curves. I stacked the curves generated for sequential samples along Z to generate the surface. The heavy black line is the 'simple' cuberoot(Z) limited to real values, i.e. the same line as in Figure 1 and requested in the original question. The green line is the complex value returned by gnuplot for `Z**(1./3)`.  For positive Z the two curves are the same.  For negative Z they lie on different regions of the complex surface.  I have confirmed that gnuplot's complex power function and the C library function [cpow](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/cpow) both return values from the same region of the surface.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your highly informative answer. I greatly appreciate it. I studied complex numbers in high school and used them a lot at university in Electricity and Magnetism. However, I still feel that I need to fill in some gaps. Would you recommend a book that I can read to get a better understanding of complex numbers? Something that let me brush up and also expand on it. Of course, I know the basics, but would like to go beyond that. Thank you again for your outstanding answer.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't have any specific recommendations for books. If your original question is now resolved, please click on the widget to accept the answer so that it is marked and can be found by people with a similar question in the future.

Comment: I get an error `undefined variable: I`, I guess the definition `I = {0,1}` is missing.